# Rspec::Matcher 'change' method with receiver and message vs. block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test the deletion of an association. The two models involved are `User` and `Cancellation`:

```
    class Cancellation < Active Record::Base
      belongs_to :taker, class_name: "User"
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :taken_cancellations, class_name: "Cancellation", foreign_key: :taker_id
    end
```

In my test, I've got the following code:

```
describe "Admin Calendar" do
  subject { page } 

  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Taker User") }
  let(:cancellation) { FactoryGirl.create(:cancellation, start_at: 2.days.from_now, taker: user) }

  before do
    sign_in admin
    visit edit_admin_cancellation_path cancellation
  end

  #...

  describe "Edit Page" do
    it 'Making it available' do
      expect { click_link "Make it available" }.to change(cancellation.reload, :taker).from(user).to nil
    end
  end
end
```

`click_link 'Make it available` will trigger `user.taken_cancellations.delete @cancellation` in the controller.

The test fails with this error:

```
taker should have been changed to nil, but is now #<User id: 1, name: "Taker User"...
```

from the guides for the `let` method:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

> The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.

To me, it looks like that the `change` method is creating a new `cancellation` after the action instead of looking at the memoized one. I wasn't expecting this behavior.

The test passes when using a block, like so:

```
expect { click_link "Make it available" }.to change { cancellation.reload.taker }.from(user).to nil
```

Can anybody explain if I'm correct? Why these different behaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first form, `cancellation.reload` is evaluated once and the resulting object sent the message `taker` before and after the invocation of the `click_link` method. In other words, the `cancellation` object is *not* reloaded after `click_link` is called.

In the second form, `cancellation.reload.taker` is evaluated in its entirety before and after the call to `click_link`, so the `reload` has a chance to take effect after the database update has taken place.

Note, though, that depending on your configuration, the server that is processing the result of `click_link` may be executing in a separate thread, so in any event there is a race condition between the update of the database and the test assertion.

Comment: Makes all the sense. Thank you!